# magento 1.9 silver exchange extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

My store based on **Silver**. Am plan to introduce **Silver exchange** concept.

I mean customer can exchange their sliver and buy new one.

My question Is there any `extension` for related my concept ?